# Isomer Identification Using Condensed Structural Formulae

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

> Which of the following pairs are isomers?
>
> a) $\ce{C5H10}$ and $\ce{C10H20}$
> b) $\ce{CH3(CH2)4CH3}$ and $\ce{CH3(CH2)3CH3}$
> c) $\ce{CH3CH(CH3)(CH2)2CH3}$ and $\ce{CH3(CH2)2CH(CH3)2}$
> d) $\ce{(CH3)3CH}$ and $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH3}$

My textbook says the answer is C). I beg to differ. I think it is D). C) is just a different way of writing 2-methylpentane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **isomer**
>
> One of several species (or molecular entities ) that have the same atomic composition (molecular formula) but different line formulae or different stereochemical formulae and hence different physical and/or chemical properties.

Source:
*Pure and Applied Chemistry*, 1994, 66, 1077 (Glossary of terms used in physical organic chemistry (IUPAC Recommendations 1994))
*Pure and Applied Chemistry*, 1996, 68, 2193 (Basic terminology of stereochemistry (IUPAC Recommendations 1996))

**a)**
C<sub>5</sub>H<sub>10</sub>
and
C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>20</sub>

different chemical formula → not isomeric

**b)**
CH<sub>3</sub>(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>4</sub>CH<sub>3</sub> = hexane (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>14</sub>)
and
CH<sub>3</sub>(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>3</sub>CH<sub>3</sub> = pentane (C<sub>5</sub>H<sub>12</sub>)

different chemical formula → not isomeric

**c)**
CH<sub>3</sub>CH(CH<sub>3</sub>)(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH<sub>3</sub> = 2-methylpentane (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>14</sub>)
and
CH<sub>3</sub>(CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub>2</sub>CH(CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub> = 2-methylpentane (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>14</sub>)

same chemical formula and same structural formula → identical, not isomeric

**d)**
(CH<sub>3</sub>)<sub>3</sub>CH = isobutane (C<sub>4</sub>H<sub>10</sub>)
and
CH<sub>3</sub>CH<sub>2</sub>CH<sub>2</sub>CH<sub>3</sub> = butane (C<sub>4</sub>H<sub>10</sub>)

same chemical formula and different structural formula → isomeric